# How to filter an list by the value of an inner dict with jq?

Tags: json, jq

Giving the input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get the dicts with the name `foo`, so the expecting output is:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "value": 1
},
{
  "name": "foo",
  "value": 2
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```sh
jq '.[] | select(.name == "foo")'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Lfb2eF6Xvp)